# Establishing many-to-many relationships between two entities with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, orm

I have a Windows Forms app project in C#. I am using Entity Framework Core. And I am beginner in EF Core.

I have two entities: `Machine`, `User`.

A user can have multiple machines, and machine can have multiple users. I want to establish a many-to-many relationship. The class structure I've created in its current state is not suitable for the task I mentioned because when I create a migration like this, the table is generated as follows, and I cannot create it with the name I want.

These are my classes:

```
internal class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }  
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}

internal class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
    public List<Machine> machines { get; set; }
}
```

The tables generated in the database are as follows:

[image: Db table]

**1.** Is the method I used correct to establish a many-to-many relationship, and if it is correct, how can I create the table and its columns with the desired name?
For example: in `MachineUser` table there are two columns named `machinesid` and `usersid`. I want to change the names of these columns as I desire like x or y.

**2.** How can I specify the owner side in this many-to-many relationship?

**NOTE**: I haven't made any configuring in `OnModelConfiguring` method.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a MachinUser entity by yourself and name it anything you want.
This table should have two properties(MachineId, UserId, or anything you call them) and you should put the navigation properties in this entity like below:

```
internal class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }   
}

internal class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }    
}

internal class MachineUser
{
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
    public List<Machine> machines { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key for this table is both MachineId and UserId.